# Get only a simple number in C/C++

Tags: c, stdio

I've a function `stoi` like that:

```
static int *stoi(const char *c) {
    int *r = new int[2];
    r[1] = sscanf(c, "%d", &r[0]);
    return r;
}
```

When I give `c = "a5"` for example, it doesn't work.

When I give `c = "543336535"`, it works.

But when I give `c = "45sdfff-sdbsdf esg5sq4f"` it will return `r[0] = 45`, and I don't want that because there is some non-digit characters after `45`...

I only want my function to read a number-only string.

Comment: Pick a _single_ language -- C or C++?

Comment: Anyone, if it's possible in C, in C, else, in C++.

Comment: `new int[2]` is a poor style in C++, use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: @Quent42340 : Of course it's possible in C. ;-]

Answer (score 5):

For a minimal change to the code you already have, you can use the `%n` feature of `sscanf`:

```
int chars_read;
r[1] = sscanf(c, "%d%n", &r[0], &chars_read);
```

If `chars_read` is less than the length of the string, then `sscanf` didn't consume all the characters, so the string didn't consist entirely of a single integer.

[The Linux documentation for `scanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) points out that the additional example introduced by [Technical Corrigendum 1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/tc1.htm) contradicts the standard, but in the meantime, the standard was updated to resolve the conflict. Here's how you can interpret the results in the face of uncertain behavior of `sscanf` implementations you might encounter:

```
switch (r[1]) {
  case EOF: // empty string
    break;
  case 0: // doesn't start with numeric characters
    break;
  case 1: // starts with number; sscanf follows standards
  case 2: // starts with number; sscanf follows TC1
    if (c[chars_read] == '\0')
      r[1] = 1; // we read entire string
    else
      r[1] = 0; // didn't read entire string; pretend we read nothing
    break;
  default: // shouldn't happen
    assert(FALSE);
}
```

Comment: The [`scanf` manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) warns against using the return value of scanf with a `%n` format. It might be better to set `r[1] = (chars_read==strlen(c))`.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Dave. I think my revision covers everything now. If not, please edit.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C, you can use `strtol` to do what you might call a tentative conversion. It will give you a pointer to the end of the data it could convert. If that's not the end of the string, you had at least some garbage following whatever it could convert.

If you're using C++, you probably want to use Boost `lexical_cast`, which will succeed if the entire input converted to the destination type, but throw an exception if any of it didn't convert.